# Infinite union of countable sets proof.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I understand how to prove that the union of 2 countable sets is countable. I then began to think we can use induction to say that the countable union of countable sets are also countable. However my textbook says otherwise. How come? Also it says that numbers arranged into a square like so

1 3 6 10 15 . . .

2 5 9 14 . . .

4 8 13 . . .

7 12 . . .

11 . . .
.
.
.

proves this theorem. I fail to make the connection.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

An infinite union of countable sets may not be countable. For example, take the sets

$$A_x = \{n+x| n\in\mathbb N\}$$

so each set $A_x$ is *countable*, but $$\bigcup_{x\in[0,1]} A_x = \mathbb R,$$

which is not countable.

---

However, your "square proof" would work fine to prove the statement

> A *countable* union of *countable* sets is *countable*.

The proof would work because you can map the set $\mathbb N$ to the countable union of countable sets, by mapping $1$ to the first element of the first set, then $2$ to the first element of the second set, $3$ to the first element of the first set, $4$ to the first element of the third set, and so on.

---

This statement would be very hard to prove by induction, however, because induction can only ever prove statements that are true *for each element* of $\mathbb N$, not statements about the set as a whole.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks alot. My textbook must have a type because it claims that an infinite union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: @benssiao What book is that, and what page is the typo on, so we can all correct it in our copies?

Comment: @benssiao Are you sure the textbook doesn't say "countably infinite"?

Comment: Isnt countable and countably infinite the same? In the sense they are the same as saying a function is a bijection between N and A where A is any set. I have Stephen Abbott's second edition of Understanding Analysis. I am looking at theorem 1.5.8 ii on page 29.

Comment: @benssiao Not entirely. Countable may also be finite. But even if you mean countable as "countably infinite", still, the terms *infinite* and *countably infinite* are certainly not the same.

Comment: Oh sorry for the confusion and thanks for the clarification. Has anyone checked the book yet?

Comment: Countable and countably infinite can mean the same.

Comment: @benssiao The theorem says "if $A_n$ is a countable set for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $\cup^{\infty}_{n=1}A_n$ is countable." I.e. a countably infinite union of countable sets is countable. Not a typo.